# How to rollback to old analysis in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, rollback

Accidentally changed the underlying branch for a sonar project and ran the analysis and now after reverting the to original branch, all the issues marked as wont fix are again show on the dashboard. Is there any option available in sonarqube to the previous state of the project which was working fine or any possible solution to restore the  quality profile.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to restore the previous state. SonarQube allows to delete analysis result (`Activity` tab in 7.1), but all except the last. It means that you can fix statistics by removing accidental analysis, but you must fix issues statuses manually.

[image: activity tab -> delete analysis]

Comment: I don't see delete analysis result operator on activity tab, anywhere I can find it?

Comment: I added a screenshot. You need the `Administer` permission to see the `Delete Analysis` button.